# Play Framework debugging problems with Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, playframework

I am working through the YABE tutorial and would like to throw the debugger on to see why the captcha isnt working correctly.

I am using Eclipse and Play 1.2.

Here is the error im getting when trying to run as:

ERROR: transport error 202: bind failed: Address already in use
ERROR: JDWP Transport dt_socket failed to initialize, TRANSPORT_INIT(510)
JDWP exit error AGENT_ERROR_TRANSPORT_INIT(197): No transports initialized [../../../src/share/back/debugInit.c:690]
FATAL ERROR in native method: JDWP No transports initialized, jvmtiError=AGENT_ERROR_TRANSPORT_INIT(197)

Ideas?

Comment: Be aware that you have to launch the application firts, then connect debugger

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try changing the JPDA port that Play listens on.  It looks like the default port, 8000, is already in use by something else.

You can do this by modifying the "jpda.port" property in "conf/application.conf".  Be sure to also modify the Eclipse JPDA launch file (the one that was generated by the `play eclipsify` command) if that is what you are using to start the debugging session.

Comment: im using Eclipse to start the debug session like this:

Run > Debug Configurations > Debug

Comment: Cool. Able to get it to work watching this video. http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ydJPG8enROs

Comment: side note. Which is the better IDE? Eclipse or IntelliJ for Play?

Answer (score 3):

Its all there in the message itself!, "Address already in use", ie. the port numbers (8000 or 9000) may be already used/reserved by some other app or you may have a stale Play instance started earlier.

Comment: I kill the browser thats on 9000 and get this error:

Cannot conenct to VM, Socket is closed.