# Error using Play Framework debug command

Tags: java, debugging, playframework

I try to launch my play project in debug mode with the `play debug` command, and it display me an error I can't resolve, despite of Google research... I found many topics about it, but no solution worked for me. Tried to change debug port, run as administrator, disable firewall..

Error message :

```
ERROR: transport error 202: bind failed: Permission denied
ERROR: JDWP Transport dt_socket failed to initialize, TRANSPORT_INIT(510)
JDWP exit error AGENT_ERROR_TRANSPORT_INIT(197): No transports initialized [../../../src/share/back/debugInit.c:750]
FATAL ERROR in native method: JDWP No transports initialized, jvmtiError=AGENT_ERROR_TRANSPORT_INIT(197)
```

NOTE : On my computer, Windows Kernel is using port 9999

Have you got the same error and found a fix for it ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of this?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7341449/play-framework-debugging-problems-with-eclipse

Comment: No, this topic has an `Address already in use` error, and for me it's a `Permission denied`

Comment: How have you tried to change the port? Also you have any antivirus that can be blocking it?

Comment: I've tried the command `play debug "run 1111"`, and for the antivirus, a colleague has tested with it and it works (Windows Defender)

Answer (score 1):

You could try

- Deactivating any antivirus or firewall;
- Check ports in use by netstat command
- Changing play.bat debug port (at play's folder root) and save it

Hope it helps